# table, td style in new theme messes up the Google custom Results, How to Fix?

Tags: css, styles, wordpress-theming

Today I changed the wordpress theme of my blog but the table, td style in the theme style file is messing up the whole Google custom results. I know one solution is to remove all those styles from the file and let Google use its own style. But I also want to keep those for the tables which I occasionally use in my posts.

Can anyone help me how to keep the existing table, td style of my theme while forcing the Google custom search engine to ignore these classes and load its own??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example you set `TD` class like this

```
.td_class { background-color:red}
```

you can add the class name to your table and set `td_class` as child class

```
.table_class {}
.table_class .td_class {background:red}
```

**EDIT**
if you don't want to change each tables classes , you can do it `on-the-fly` with [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) 
for example your code is like this :

```
<html>
 <div id="MainDiv">
 <table>......</table>
 <table>......</table>
 <table>......</table>
 </div>
 //goole code here // separated from MainDiv
</html>
```

you can use this code to change table's class

```
$(#MainDiv table).each(function(){
      $(this).addClass('addClass')
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this way I'll have to edit every table which I have ever created. won't I?